# sites displayed perfectly in browser except IE 6

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, ssl, virtualhost

i stumbled in an error, i have apache httpd configured virtual host to serve as reverse proxy, here is my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html

###redirect permanent####
Redirect permanent / https://example2.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName example2.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/proxyhost/public_html

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/proxyhost_ssl_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/proxyhost_ssl_requests.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-8]" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/test1$ /test1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/test2$ /test2/ [R]

ProxyPass /test1/ ajp://host1:8009/test/
ProxyPassReverse /test1/ ajp://host1:8009/test/
ProxyPass /test2/ ajp://host2:8009/test2/
ProxyPassReverse /test2/ ajp://host2:8009/test2/

ProxyPreserveHost On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
</VirtualHost>


<Directory /var/www/proxyhost/public_html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

the problem is, using configuration above is perfectly fine with browser like chrome and firefox. But when i tried to access the web using old IE 6 on win server 2003, the page cannot be loaded. I tried to access using http (comment the redirect function) and https, nothing shows up.

this is the error log

```
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.502672 2018] [alias:warn] [pid 22755] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/directory-enabled/DIR_BRI.conf at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.502679 2018] [alias:warn] [pid 22755] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/directory-enabled/DIR_BTN.conf at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.502685 2018] [alias:warn] [pid 22755] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/directory-enabled/DIR_MANDIRI.conf at line 1 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.503602 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 22755] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.504221 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 22755] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.505594 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 22755] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.507996 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22755] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 28 13:23:32.508016 2018] [core:notice] [pid 22755] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Any suggestion to resolve the issue? because i don't have authority to force our users to upgrade their OS and browser.

Thank you,
Galih

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the browser, you have configuration errors to fix.  The `Alias`, the `No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor`, ...

As for the SSL error, you are using SNI (`Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)`).  IE 6 does NOT support SNI.  So Apache does not know which site IE 6 users are trying to reach.

When Apache receives a request that is not SNI enabled, it looks at the port (here 443), and processes the request with the first VirtualHost is finds on port 443 (top down in the configuration).  Therefore the IE 6 user will always get the certificate identified in the first `<VirtualHost *:443>` present in your configuration.

At this point you have 2 choices.

1. Do not support IE 6.  Put a note on your site that old versions do not work with your site (and frankly, IE 6 is **very** old, all business web sites I know do not support it anymore).
2. Put the default `<VirtualHost *:443>` you want IE 6 users to see first in your configuration.  But they will not be able to reach the others.

---

**EDIT 22:45**: if IE6 users cannot access the http version of your site either, it is possible that:

- they do not connect at all, check your Apache logs.  You should put the logs in debug mode (`LogLevel debug`).
- they connect, but Apache does not understand the request.  Again check Apache logs.
- they receive a page but IE crashes trying to render the display.  That can be caused by JavaScript code that IE6 is to old to understand.  Validate if the browser receives a page or not.  I do not know if you can view some console in IE6 (I know newest version do have something like that).  If the Javascript fails to execute, you will not see the page in  your IE.  You could try to access a very simple test page.

Comment: hi nic, thanks for your response, if i put virtualhost for ssl in the first order does it make IE can access my web? because as for now, IE cannot access the web using http and https.

Comment: hi @Nic3500 the request made from IE 6 already logged in access log in apache, does it means that request has been made right? but either apache or IE cannot proprly response to request

Comment: and i cannot even test my index.html in my root document in apache

Comment: Ok, but does your index.html contain any javascript?  Put a super simple test page with just a `<p>TEST</p>`.  If that works, it means the javascript in the real page is not compatible with IE6 (or other code in the page).

Comment: Hi Nic, my test page only contain text -> Maintenance Undergoing